# Xcode header search path is not correct after pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, xcconfig

I have an iOS Xcode project that uses cocoapods. I made changes in the Podfile to remove a pod. While running pod install, it complained about cocoapods needing an update. so I updated cocoapods and it upgraded to 1.7.5 from 1.5.3.
I ran the pod install after this which went through fine but the header search path seems to be messed up.

I have my project's config file that sets HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and also does #include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XYZ/Pods-XYZ.release.xcconfig". The pods config file has $(inherited).

But when I look at the resolved value for HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Xcode it contains only the header search path set in pods config file but not the ones set in my project's config file.

Because of this problem, the build fails. Any help with fixing this problem is appreciated. Thanks!